# Is it possible to change printing font size of TextEdit in OS X

Tags: macos, textedit

The way I have it now, TextEdit prints with huge fonts size (like 24 points or so). I'd like to change that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TextEdit, check the menu File / Page Setup, and confirm that the paper size is set correctly, and that 'scale' is set to 100%.

If that's correct, the defaults (TextEdit / Preferences... / New Document / Font) should be the font size printed. Note existing documents may already have a larger font size set. Make sure you're viewing the document at the original size (View / Actual size, or Apple-0), set the font size as you want it, and check out the preview in the Print dialogue box.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, but I see that the problem is that I have MacBook Air 13" and I have to set the font to 15 points, otherwise it is too small to read on the screen. But it is too big for printing. Reducing scaling to 75% in page setup works fine. Is there a way to make that to stick? I see that I need to change it to 75% every time I print.

Comment: You should use the View menu to change how the text is displayed on the screen. Changing the font size will affect both print and screen, whereas the View / zoom settings will only affect the screen. I think you will have most success with the print 'Scaling' set to 100%, font size set to 12 (or your desired print size), and use the zoom settings to make it readable on screen. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to set the default zoom level - it resets to 100% for every file in my tests - so you may have to get familiar with the keyboard shortcut (shift+apple+. for me).

Answer (score 0):

This situation arises from the fact that you are viewing your text through a small window, and TextEdit is attempting to print the contents of that window on your printer so that the printed page looks like your window. That's one kind of WYSIWYG. To get the kind of WYSIWYG you want, expect, and are familiar with, simply:

**Turn on "Wrap To Page" under the "Format" menu (or hit ⇧⌘W)**.

Margins will appear, adjusting the fonts and line breaks to the way they will appear when printed.

Similarly, people who use large windows will find that their printed font sizes are much smaller than they appear on-screen, due to the "window WYSIWYG" effect. The solution is the same: turn on page wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see me refer to wrap to page and wrap to text in my image, sorry about that but they are the same and not to be confused with wrap to window.

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE]

Comment: The question was about printed font size, not margins and wrap.